# Fetch a particular tagged latest image from AWS ECR repo

Tags: amazon-web-services, repository, amazon-ecr

Is it possible to fetch latest image from ECR with a particular docker tag which starts from develop like `developXXX`?
I am able to see latest image from a repo with this:

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name reponame --output text --region eu-west-1 --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*].imageTags[*]' | tr '\t' '\n' | tail -1
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by `fetch`. You can surely pull images from ECR with tags. [Pulling an image](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-pull-ecr-image.html) and if you are talking about fetching information for a particular image with tag . You still can do that [list-images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecr/list-images.html#list-images) with `filter`

Comment: I want to get the tag of latest image in  repo which has name starting with develop.

Answer (score 1):

Matching 'develop' keyword from all fetched image and returning the latest one with `tail -1`.

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name reponame --output text --region eu-west-1 --query 'sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[*].imageTags[*]' | grep -w "develop" | tail -1
```

You can change logic in `grep -w "develop"` part which can fit to your condition

Answer (score 0):

This query will get the latest image with a tag containing "develop".

```
--query 'reverse(sort_by(imageDetails, &imagePushedAt)).[[?imageTags[?contains(@,`develop`)]].[imagePushedAt,imageDigest,imageTags][0]]'
```

First it sorts so the most recently pushed image is first, then selects images with a tag containing "develop", then selects the first result.  If it's working for you, you probably want to return only the `imageDigest` and add `--output text --no-paginate` so you just get the ID as a string.